# Current path is not showing in terminal for new CentOS user

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, centos

I have created a new user on a CentOS server. I don't know why, but when I connect with this new user the current path is not showing in the terminal. Instead, I can see '-bash-4.2'. What is the meaning of -bash-4.2 and how can I display the current path (such as /home)?

[image]

Comment: "Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."
Only typing the text into the question is not actually helpful here. The snip illustrates much better what is the issue and it provides a better visualization. I don't know how to write white text on black background here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current prompt variable (`$PS1`) contains something like `\s-\v\$` which corresponds to the name of the shell and its version. To have the prompt display the current path (along with the trailing `$` you currently have), set PS1 with this:

```
PS1='$PWD\$ '
```

Using either of `\w` or `\W` will produce similar results, except for your home directory.

To keep this setting going forward, you'll want to set that value in your ~/.bashrc file.

See more options in the bash manual under `PROMPTING` or online at https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html#Controlling-the-Prompt